# What is the difference between pageBlockTable, dataTable and repeat?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am not sure if this is against the forum policy but just wanted to know from experienced people on what is the difference between pageBlockTable, dataTable and repeat?

This is what I have found so far on the interenet:

**apex:pageBlockTable**

```
1) uses salesforce styling
2) No need to specify the headers
3) mandatory attribute "value".
```

**apex:dataTable**

```
1) Need to specify the headers
2) we can specify custom style classes.
3) No mandatory attribute "value" unlike in pageblockTable
```

I could not find much info on the apex:repeat

Comment: Value is indeed required for apex:dataTable.

Comment: repeat is an iterator....It allows you to cycle through the dataset: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm <- This site will give you all the information you need on this question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The four basic types, [**apex:pageBlockTable**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm), [**apex:dataTable**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm), [**apex:dataList**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataList.htm), and [**apex:repeat**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) are all basically the same thing, but present different renderings.

**apex:pageBlockTable** represents a table formatted and styled to look like a related list table.

**apex:dataTable** is an unstyled table suitable for use anywhere outside of a **apex:pageBlock** (but may be used within one).

**apex:dataList** renders a `ul` or `ol` element (unordered or ordered list, respectively), with `li` (list item) elements comprising the rows.

**apex:repeat** allows any arbitrary output based on a template. The four elements require **value** and **var** attributes, iterate over a collection of some sort, may generally be nested inside each other, and are limited to 1,000/10,000 rows of output, depending on the [**apex:page**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm)'s **readOnly** attribute.

Edit: As pointed out in the comment, the main difference with **apex:pageBlockTable**, compared to the other three, is it must appear in a **apex:pageBlock** or **apex:pageBlockSection**, while the other types can be rendered anywhere that Visualforce is allowed. There's a very specific limitation about **apex:pageBlock** not being available in email templates, as well, so you'd naturally have to use one of the other three types of iterators.

Comment: n.b. `"Several standard Visualforce components are not available for use within <messaging:emailTemplate>. These include <apex:detail>, <apex:pageBlock> and all related pageBlock components,"` -- no pageBlocktable in VF email templates

Comment: @crop1645 I did mean to mention that, as well as the fact that apex:pageBlockTable can't just appear free-standing by itself, but actually has to be inside a apex:pageBlock.

Comment: sfdcfox -- I was careful to use the `n.b` = `nota bene` = `note well; take notice.` - not meant as a criticism, just an addenda for some future reader of your answer

Comment: also related article http://www.thephani.com/difference-between-pageblocktabe-datatable-repeat/

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Thanks for the suggested edit. I've also added reference links to the various objects.